# Error: spawn sh ENOENT Node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter, raspberry-pi, sh, child-process

I am trying to trigger PIFM on my raspberry Pi by tweets from a specific twitter account using node.js. However when I run twitpifm.js on the command line:

```
node twitpifm.js
```

I get the following error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn sh ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:439:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:469:11)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
```

I am using this version of PIFM on my PI2

https://github.com/asmello/fm_transmitter

I have written a script (test.sh) that will start PIFm from command line without parameters

```
 #!/bin/bash
    /home/pi/PIFm/fm_transmitter/bin/Release/fm_transmitter music.wav 103.50
```

I am aware that I need to need to use a child_process within my node.js to activate this shell script but am having trouble with it;

First I invoke child process with:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn // child process.spawn
```

I then try to trigger the shell with the following:

```
function thisTweet(){

    spawn('sh', ['test.sh'], {  // shell script I want to run.
    cwd:' /home/pi/Desktop/Twitter', // current working directory where my twitpifm.js file is 
    env: Object.assign({}, process.env, { PATH: process.env.PATH + '/home/pi/PIFm/fm_transmitter' }) //this sets a path to where test.sh is
    })
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Ok..I got a solution that seems to be working using . execfile from here:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback

This code worked:

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const child = execFile('sh', ['/home/pi/Desktop/twitter/test'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
}
```

This lets me execute a shell script from node.js